# Parse PDF Fails Because of Missing OpenType Layout Tables

Tags: java, pdfbox, truetype

i need to parse a PDF file with PDFBox (version 2.0.7), but i only get lots of warnings of the kind

> Sep 02, 2017 10:18:24 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2
>   WARNING: Found CFF/OTF but expected embedded TTF font
>   AAAAAC+UniversLTStd-LightCn
>
> Sep 02, 2017 10:18:24 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2
>      INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font
>   AAAAAC+UniversLTStd-LightCn are not implemented in PDFBox and will be
>   ignored

Do i have any possibility to solve that problem by e.g. loading a certain font before parsing that PDF or is there no chance that i can parse that document?
Alternatively is there another PDF parsing framework i could try with better luck?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I do not see that your parsing "fails". The first line is a WARNING that your PDF is not according to the specification but PDFBox is nice and parses it anyway. The second line INFO means that parsing is fine but that layout tables are not supported. This is relevant for you if you're e.g. Thai, Indian or Arab and want to create a PDF. No, it won't change by loading something. Other parsing software may or may not tell you their observations in logs.

Comment: I didn't say that the parsing failed, but i wonder if there is a possibility that i can extract the text contents from that PDF without asking the customer to adjust that document in order to meet the specifications.

Comment: Your title is "Parse PDF Fails" but I have not seen proof that it did, and you didn't mention text extraction. You should still be able to get your text - if not, it will have other reasons, see here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#notext . I can bring more details if you share the file.

Comment: As @TilmanHausherr indicates, there isn't much we can do unless you share representative example PDFs and show your pivotal code.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you used the ExtractText cmdline utility. The default behaviour of PDFBox' ExtractText utility is to write the extracted text into a file (same name as your input file but with suffix ".txt"). It does not show the extracted text on console. If you want to see the extracted text as console output, you have to specify the parameter "-console".